# How to get a shapefile DBF encoding?

Tags: python, ogr, unicode, utf-8, encode

I wrote a python code that is used in different countries.
It process a shapefile DBF, that can be encoded in any of the local langage (or being provided by another foreign partner), or even in ascii.
Therefore, I can't make any assumption on the encoding of the DBF.
It happens that some caracters (eg. French accents) break my code.

Therefore, I would like to do something like:

```
codec=.....[the function I am looking for]
codec.encode(string, "utf-8")
```

Is there any function in ogr to get the Shapefile DBF encoding, or do I need some tricks to guess it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is true. You ***can't*** make any assumption on the encoding of the DBF. Some modern shapefiles created by Esri might have a codepage (`.cpg`) file, but it might not even be correct. In my experience to date, it can sometimes take quite a bit of effort to determine the encoding of any given dBase file.

Comment: I feared to read that... Do you see a series of tests I could run to guess the encoding ? At least how to guess the encoding for French speaking and Spanish speaking users?

Comment: Not really. Most of my encoding encounters have been ASCII files with several *different* encoding schemes, used intermittently (with random control character noise added), the memory of which can make me bolt upright at night. Sorry.